# trying to print a group from a regex match in python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, for-loop, regex-group

I am trying to print the group info from my regex match match.
My script matches my regex versus line in my file, so that's working.

I have based this on the python regex tutorial btw ... 
I'm a python newbie (with some perl experience) :)

```
import re

file = open('read.txt', 'r')

p = re.compile("""
.*,\\\" 
(.*)            # use grouping here with brackets so we can fetch value with group later on
\\\"
""", re.VERBOSE)

i = 0


for line in file:
    if p.match(line):
        print p.group()   #this is the problematic group line
        i += 1
```

Comment: What's the question/problem? What does an input line look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match()` returns a match object - you need to assign it to something. Try

```
for line in file:
    m = p.match(line)
    if m:
        print m.group()
        i += 1
```

Comment: amazing, this works like a charm, just had to change m.group() to m.group(1) because it was giving me too much info, which I find strange because I didn't enclose the 1st part in parentheses in my regular expression p

Comment: @bennethos [```match.group()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group), without an argument, returns the entire string matched by the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the regex object returned by match. Try this:

```
for line in file:
    matched = p.match(line)
    if matched:
        print matched.group()   # this should now work
        i += 1
```

Comment: works too , thx so much, same issue as the 1st poster though. it's giving me too much with matched.group() so using matched.group(1)